# Try/do pattern implementation in Java

Tags: java, java-me, design-patterns

I'm a fan of the try/do (or trier/doer) pattern, which is best implemented in C# using `out` parameters, e.g.:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse("2012-06-18", out date))
{
    //Do something with date
}
```

I'm currently working on a Java 1.5 project, for which I'm implementing the try/do pattern using a new class called TryResult which is returned from any methods which implement the try/do pattern:

```
public class TryResult<ResultType> {

    private boolean mSuccess = false;
    private ResultType mResult = null;

    public TryResult(boolean success, ResultType result) {
        super();
        this.mSuccess = success;
        this.mResult = result;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return mSuccess;
    }

    public ResultType getResult() {
        return mResult;
    }

}
```

This is working well, but I will be porting this code to a different platform which uses J2ME, and therefore generics aren't available.

My current options are to either remove the generics from the `TryResult` class above and using plain old `Object` and casting, or make a new class for the types I will end up using (e.g. `StringTryResult`).

Is there a better way to implement this pattern on J2ME/Java 1.3?

Comment: With Object and casting.

Comment: @lukas Thanks for your comment. I guess it wasn't clear, but that's what I meant by 'removing generics'. I'm hoping that there's a better solution though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to implement is called a [Maybe monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#The_Maybe_monad) in functional languages.

There are experiments to do this in java, see [here](http://logicaltypes.blogspot.hu/2011/09/monads-in-java.html) and [here](http://www.irekjozwiak.com/entry/2009/06/13/Monads-for-Java-C---programmers.html).

The problem is, Java's type system is unfortunately not advanced enough to support this on a large scale.. Also, the standard libraries do not support anything like that, which reduces the use of such a construct to your own code only :(

See [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) for languages that support this.

As far as Java ME goes, I'd think twice about implementing special types just for the sake of this. It is a nice in idea theory, however, it would make things just more difficult, eg. duplicating all types in your whole app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, definitely some interesting reading here. Regarding implementing special types, I expect to concede to practicality and use a special type for the most common result types (e.g. `StringTryResult` will be commonly used) and use `Object` and casting for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't endorse this an any way, but a really low-tech way to do "`out`" variables in Java is to use single element arrays:

```
String input = ...;
Date[] date = { null };
if (DateParser.tryParse(input, date)) {
  System.out.println(date[0]);
}
```